# Troubleshooting LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS Issue on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy, node-modules

I am trying to run a GitHub repo that simulates the bike riding data via Bluetooth Low Energy. I am facing **LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS** whenever I try to run it on a Windows machine.
Below is the full stack trace of the error that I have been facing

```
Error: LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS
    at Interface.claim (C:\Users\simulator\zwack\node_modules\usb\usb.js:286:14)
    at BluetoothHciSocket.bindUser (C:\Users\simulator\zwack\node_modules\@abandonware\bluetooth-hci-socket\lib\usb.js:92:28)
    at BluetoothHciSocket.bindRaw (C:\Users\simulator\zwack\node_modules\@abandonware\bluetooth-hci-socket\lib\usb.js:48:8)
    at Hci.init (C:\Users\simulator\zwack\node_modules\bleno\lib\hci-socket\hci.js:110:35)
    at BlenoBindings.init (C:\Users\simulator\zwack\node_modules\bleno\lib\hci-socket\bindings.js:97:13)
    at Bleno.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simulator\zwack\node_modules\bleno\lib\bleno.js:49:22)
    at Bleno.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at _addListener (node:events:556:14)
    at Bleno.addListener (node:events:605:10)
    at new ZwackBLE (C:\Users\simulator\zwack\lib\zwack-ble-sensor.js:56:9) {
  errno: -3
}
```

This is the GitHub repo that I am trying to run via cmd command prompt (as administrator)

https://github.com/paixaop

Comment: which repo. which branch, which source code?

Comment: @Risto This is the GitHub repo that I am trying to run via cmd command prompt (as administrator)

https://github.com/paixaop